# Use NPOI(C#) to modify an existing chart from an existing XLSX

Tags: c#, .net, xlsx, npoi

We have a workbook.xlsx with charts in its first sheet. How can we modify these charts? Like add "data labels" or change their "axis labels" position?

We can open the workbook (`new XSSFWorkbook`), get the sheet (`workbook.GetSheet`) and even reach the charts:

```
  XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.CreateDrawingPatriarch() as XSSFDrawing;
  var charts = drawing.GetCharts();
  var chart = charts[1];
```

But that's how far we can go. There are not much properties, more kin of factories. And all available examples are about creating new charts.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you manage to set range for the chart?@gpe

Comment: No sorry. We switch to another library for other reasons.

Comment: Can you share which library? epplus?

Comment: Exact. Are you a spy?

Comment: Thanks. No I am not a spy.